# Remove quotes from start and end of string in PHP

Tags: php, string

I have strings like these:

```
"my value1" => my value1
"my Value2" => my Value2
myvalue3 => myvalue3
```

I need to get rid of `"` (double-quotes) in end and start, if these exist, but if there is this kind of character inside String then it should be left there. Example:

```
"my " value1" => my " value1
```

How can I do this in PHP - is there function for this or do I have to code it myself?

Comment: What to do in the case of `""Hello " World""`?

Comment: ""Hello " World"" => "Hello " World"

Comment: Not sure if I'm missing something, when I see all the complex regular expressions.. But `preg_replace('/(^"|"$)/', '', '""Hello " World""')` returns `"Hello " World"`. Or even `'/^"|"$/'` as pattern works too.

Answer (score 114, accepted):

The literal answer would be

```
trim($string,'"'); // double quotes
trim($string,'\'"'); // any combination of ' and "
```

It will remove all leading and trailing quotes from a string.

If you need to remove strictly the first and the last quote in case they exist, then it could be a regular expression like this

```
preg_replace('~^"?(.*?)"?$~', '$1', $string); // double quotes
preg_replace('~^[\'"]?(.*?)[\'"]?$~', '$1', $string); // either ' or " whichever is found
```

If you need to remove only in case the leading and trailing quote are strictly paired, then use the function from [Steve Chambers' answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25353877/285587)

However, if your goal is to **read a value from a CSV file**, [fgetcsv](https://www.php.net/fgetcsv) is the only correct option. It will take care of all the edge cases, stripping the value enclosures as well.

Comment: Good function indeed but OP wants to leave the " in center and only remove at start and end...

Comment: If the second character is also '"', or penultimate one too, then that will also be stripped.  If these are significant then trim falls down.  It depends slightly on the actual data.  See answer by user783322.

Comment: Speak in plain word: "trim() will remove consecutive quotes from start or from end. However, we just want to remove very first and very last quotes only. Meaning, this shouldn't be an accpetable answer.

Comment: It seems like what I need, but I'm not the one who asked it.

Comment: This shouldn't be the accepted answer. What if a quote is part of the string? `"this is double-quote -> ""` will output `this is double-quote -> `
which means you've missed an integral part of the string.

Comment: Beware of `trim($string, '"')`. Consider `$string = '"\"love\""'`. The output is \love"

Answer (score 23):

I had a similar need and wrote a function that will remove leading and trailing single or double quotes from a string:

```
/**
 * Remove the first and last quote from a quoted string of text
 *
 * @param mixed $text
 */
function stripQuotes($text) {
  return preg_replace('/^(\'[^\']*\'|"[^"]*")$/', '$2$3', $text);
}
```

This will produce the outputs listed below:

```
Input text         Output text
--------------------------------
No quotes       => No quotes
"Double quoted" => Double quoted
'Single quoted' => Single quoted
"One of each'   => "One of each'
"Multi""quotes" => Multi""quotes
'"'"@";'"*&^*'' => "'"@";'"*&^*'
```

Regex demo (showing what is being matched/captured): https://regex101.com/r/3otW7H/8

Comment: For me, I need to add grouping parentheses in the regular expression so that $2 and $3 will return the middle of the string, like so... (note that there are 3 sets of parentheses, not 1) `function stripQuotes($text) { return preg_replace('/^(\'([^\']*)\'|"([^"]*)")$/', '$2$3', $text); }`

Answer (score 9):

`trim` will remove all instances of the char from the start and end if it matches the pattern you provide, so:

```
$myValue => '"Hi"""""';
$myValue=trim($myValue, '"');
```

Will become:

```
$myValue => 'Hi'.
```

Here's a way to only remove the first and last char if they match:

```
$output=stripslashes(trim($myValue));

// if the first char is a " then remove it
if(strpos($output,'"')===0)$output=substr($output,1,(strlen($output)-1));

// if the last char is a " then remove it
if(strripos($output,'"')===(strlen($output)-1))$output=substr($output,0,-1);
```

Answer (score 4):

As much as this thread should have been killed long ago, I couldn't help but respond with what I would call the simplest answer of all. I noticed this thread re-emerging on the 17th so I don't feel quite as bad about this. :)

Using samples as provided by Steve Chambers;

```
echo preg_replace('/(^[\"\']|[\"\']$)/', '', $input);
```

Output below;

```
Input text         Output text
--------------------------------
No quotes       => No quotes
"Double quoted" => Double quoted
'Single quoted' => Single quoted
"One of each'   => One of each
"Multi""quotes" => Multi""quotes
'"'"@";'"*&^*'' => "'"@";'"*&^*'
```

This only ever removes the first and last quote, it doesn't repeat to remove extra content and doesn't care about matching ends.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old post, but just to cater for multibyte strings, there are at least two possible routes one can follow. I am assuming that the quote stripping is being done because the quote is being considered like a program / INI variable and thus is EITHER "something" or 'somethingelse' but NOT "mixed quotes'. Also, ANYTHING between the matched quotes is to be retained intact.

Route 1 - using a Regex

```
function sq_re($i) {
    return preg_replace( '#^(\'|")(.*)\1$#isu', '$2', $i );
}
```

This uses \1 to match the same type quote that matched at the beginning. the u modifier, makes it UTF8 capable (okay, not fully multibyte supporting)

Route 2 - using mb_* functions

```
function sq($i) {
    $f = mb_substr($i, 0, 1);
    $l = mb_substr($i, -1);
    if (($f == $l) && (($f == '"') || ($f == '\'')) ) $i = mb_substr($i, 1, mb_strlen( $i ) - 2);
    return $i;
}
```

Comment: I don't get the #^ at the start of the pattern, # at the end, as well as the i modifier. Isn't  ^(\'|")(.*)\1$su  all that's necessary to answer the question?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use regular expressions, look at:-

http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php

Or you could, in this instance, use substr to check if the first and then the last character of the string is a quote mark, if it is, truncate the string.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.substr.php

Comment: You definitely not **need** a regular expression.

Comment: Trim could end up removing significant quotemarks at the beginning or end of the string - I stand by regexps!

Comment: Speak in plain word: "trim() will remove consecutive quotes from start or from end. However, we just want to remove very first and very last quotes only.

Answer (score 0):

How about regex

```
//$singleQuotedString="'Hello this 'someword' and \"somewrod\" stas's SO";
//$singleQuotedString="Hello this 'someword' and \"somewrod\" stas's SO'";
$singleQuotedString="'Hello this 'someword' and \"somewrod\" stas's SO'";

$quotesFreeString=preg_replace('/^\'?(.*?(?=\'?$))\'?$/','$1' ,$singleQuotedString);
```

Output

```
Hello this 'someword' and "somewrod" stas's SO
```

Answer (score 0):

If you like performance over clarity this is the way:

```
// Remove double quotes at beginning and/or end of output
$len=strlen($output);
if($output[0]==='"') $iniidx=1; else $iniidx=0;
if($output[$len-1]==='"') $endidx=-1; else $endidx=$len-1;
if($iniidx==1 || $endidx==-1) $output=substr($output,$iniidx,$endidx);
```

The comment helps with clarity... 
brackets in an array-like usage on strings is possible and demands less processing effort than equivalent methods, too bad there isnt a length variable or a last char index

Comment: I realise the OP didn't ask about multibyte strings, but this won't work with such strings. One doesn't have to use an Regex, but they do make this fairly straightforward.