# Inserting Data to MySQL, Double Quotes Added to Fields

Tags: php, mysql, insert

I've got a script that imports data to a MySQL table and when inserting, VARCHAR and TEXT fields have double quotes on the beginning and end.  I am using `addslashes` because some of the fields are supposed to have single quotes, double quotes, commas, and semi-colons.  Here's my code:

```
$csvfile = fopen($csv_file, 'r');
$theData = fgets($csvfile);
$i = 0;
$imports = array();

while (!feof($csvfile))
{
   $csv_data[] = fgets($csvfile, 1024);
   $data = explode(",", $csv_data[$i]);
   $insert_csv = array();

   $insert_csv['id'] = md5($EventID.$PerformerID);
   $insert_csv['EventID'] = addslashes($data[0]);
   $insert_csv['Event'] = addslashes($data[1]);
   $insert_csv['PerformerID'] = addslashes($data[2]);
   $insert_csv['Performer'] = addslashes($data[3]);
   $insert_csv['Venue'] = addslashes($data[4]);
   $insert_csv['VenueID'] = addslashes($data[5]);
   $insert_csv['VenueStreetAddress'] = addslashes($data[6]);
   $insert_csv['DateTime'] = addslashes($data[7]);
   $insert_csv['PCatID'] = addslashes($data[8]);
   $insert_csv['PCat'] = addslashes($data[9]);
   $insert_csv['CCatID'] = addslashes($data[10]);
   $insert_csv['CCat'] = addslashes($data[11]);
   $insert_csv['GCatID'] = addslashes($data[12]);
   $insert_csv['GCat'] = addslashes($data[13]);
   $insert_csv['City'] = addslashes($data[14]);
   $insert_csv['State'] = addslashes($data[15]);
   $insert_csv['StateID'] = addslashes($data[16]);
   $insert_csv['Country'] = addslashes($data[17]);
   $insert_csv['CountryID'] = addslashes($data[18]);
   $insert_csv['Zip'] = addslashes($data[19]);
   $insert_csv['TicketsYN'] = addslashes($data[20]);
   $insert_csv['IMAGEURL'] = addslashes($data[23]);

   $query = "INSERT IGNORE INTO table_name(`id`, `EventID`, `Event`, `PerformerID`, `Performer`, `Venue`, `VenueID`, `VenueStreetAddress`, `DateTime`, `PCatID`, `PCat`, `CCatID`, `CCat`, `GCatID`, `GCat`, `City`, `State`, `StateID`, `Country`, `CountryID`, `Zip`, `TicketsYN`, `IMAGEURL`)
VALUES('{$insert_csv['id']}','{$insert_csv['EventID']}','{$insert_csv['Event']}','{$insert_csv['PerformerID']}','{$insert_csv['Performer']}','{$insert_csv['Venue']}','{$insert_csv['VenueID']}','{$insert_csv['VenueStreetAddress']}','{$insert_csv['DateTime']}','{$insert_csv['PCatID']}','{$insert_csv['PCat']}','{$insert_csv['CCatID']}','{$insert_csv['CCat']}','{$insert_csv['GCatID']}','{$insert_csv['GCat']}','{$insert_csv['City']}','{$insert_csv['State']}','{$insert_csv['StateID']}','{$insert_csv['Country']}','{$insert_csv['CountryID']}','{$insert_csv['Zip']}','{$insert_csv['TicketsYN']}','{$insert_csv['IMAGEURL']}')";

   $n = mysql_query($query);
   if(!mysql_query($query)){
     die("error: ".mysql_error());
 }
   $i++;
```

What is causing the double quotes and how can I remove them when inserting the rows?  I have also tried `stripslashes` on the **VALUES** part of the query but it causes an error due to fields that have single quotes, double quotes, or other delimiters.

Comment: Don't use `addslashes` (it isn't MySQL away), don't use `mysql_query` and friends (they've been removed from PHP). Do use prepared statements. Do use PDO (or `mysqli_`)

Comment: "What is causing the double quotes" — Probably something not in the code you've shared.

Comment: First i would suggest to don't use mysql. The mysql extension is deprecated and will be removed in the future: use mysqli or PDO instead

Comment: Okay, thanks for the tips about mysql.

Comment: Any guidance on inserting data without the double quotes?

Comment: The double quotes probably come from wrong csv parsing.

Comment: Okay, I am updating the code to show more.

Comment: Just search for a ready to use CSV-parser. No need to write it yourself.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9734758/remove-quotes-from-start-and-end-of-string-in-php

Comment: mysql_real_escape_string is still inserting data with double quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its possible your csv file contains fields that are delimited by double quotes. You can remove the double quotes from the fields by using the trim function. for example:

```
$insert_csv['EventID'] = trim(addslashes($data[0]), '"');
```

The above code will remove the double quote from the start and end of the $data[0] string.

Answer (score 0):

TLDR: Instead of using addslashes() use a DB-specific escape function like [mysqli_real_escape_string()](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.real-escape-string.php)

What addslashes() does is that it returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be escaped.

I was going to write the whole explanation, but I think the [php.net](http://php.net/addslashes) does a better job of explaining:

> Returns a string with backslashes before characters that need to be
>   escaped. These characters are single quote ('), double quote ("),
>   backslash () and NUL (the NULL byte).
>
> An example use of addslashes() is when you're entering data into
>   string that is evaluated by PHP. For example, O'Reilly is stored in
>   $str, you need to escape $str. (e.g. eval("echo
>   '".addslashes($str)."';"); )
>
> To escape database parameters, DBMS specific escape function (e.g.
>   mysqli_real_escape_string() for MySQL or pg_escape_literal(),
>   pg_escape_string() for PostgreSQL) should be used for security
>   reasons. DBMSes have differect escape specification for identifiers
>   (e.g. Table name, field name) than parameters. Some DBMS such as
>   PostgreSQL provides identifier escape function,
>   pg_escape_identifier(), but not all DBMS provides identifier escape
>   API. If this is the case, refer to your database system manual for
>   proper escaping method.
>
> If your DBMS doesn't have an escape function and the DBMS uses \ to
>   escape special chars, you might be able to use this function only when
>   this escape method is adequate for your database. Please note that use
>   of addslashes() for database parameter escaping can be cause of
>   security issues on most databases.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you have a csv file. I recommend using php's in-build `fgetcsv()` to read the file. This way, you will get an array for every row and then can use that array to insert into the database.

Also, you can directly import csv into mysql if you want it that way:

```
LOAD DATA INFILE 'D:/myfile.csv' 
INTO TABLE my_table 
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
ENCLOSED BY '"'
LINES TERMINATED BY '\n'
IGNORE 1 ROWS
```